# How can I calculate mean values for each day of an year from a time series data set in R?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I have a data set containing climatic data taken hourly from 01-01-2007 to 31-12-2021.
I want to calculate the mean value for a given variable (e.g. temperature) for each day of the year (1:365).

My dataset look something like this:

```
   dia        prec_h  tc_h  um_h   v_d  vm_h
   <date>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2007-01-01    0.2  22.9    89    42   3  
 2 2007-01-01    0.4  22.8    93    47   1.9
 3 2007-01-01    0    22.7    94    37   1.3
 4 2007-01-01    0    22.6    94    38   1.6
 5 2007-01-01    0    22.7    95    46   2.3
[...]
 131496 2021-12-31 0.0 24.7   87    47   2.6
```

( "[...]" stands for sequence of data from 2007 - 2014).

I first calculated daily mean temperature for each of my entry dates as follows:

```
md$dia<-as.Date(md$dia,format = "%d/%m/%Y")
m_tc<-aggregate(tc_h ~ dia, md, mean)
```

This returned me a data frame with mean temperature values for each analyzed year.

Now, I want to calculate the mean temperature for each day of the year from this data frame, i.e: mean temperature for January 1st up to December 31st.
Thus, I need to end up with a data frame with 365 rows, but I don't know how to do such calculation. Can anyone help me out?
Also, there is a complication: I have 4 leap years in my data frame. Any recommendations on how to deal with them?
Thankfully

Comment: Try `mdia <- format(md$dia, "%m-%d"); aggregate(tc_h ~ mdia, md, mean)`. The `format` instruction keeps month and day of all 4 years, then aggregate by it.

Comment: The code above is wrong, it sums `md$dia`, not `m_tc$dia`. Corrected is `mdia <- format(m_tc$dia, "%m-%d");aggregate(tc_h ~ mdia, m_tc, mean)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, it works, but I end up with a character object (366 rows, as expected); When I try to set it as data frame with as.data.frame(mdia), it returns a dataframe like object with 5297 entries, and no tc_h value.

How can I apply this code and receive a df so I can ggplot and compare with other values? Thanks!!

Comment: With the posted data `aggregate` doesn't return a character object, only the previous instruction, `format`, does. `mdia <- format(m_tc$dia, "%m-%d")` returns a character object but then it is used as the grouping variable of `aggregate`. I will post a working example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data to the function using the pipe (%>%) from R package (magrittr) and calculate the mean  values by calling R package (dplyr):

library(dplyr); library(magrittr)

tcmean<-md %>% group_by(dia) %>% summarise(m_tc=mean(tc_h))

Comment: Please include an explanation, even if minimal, of what the code does. And do [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

First simulate a data set with the relevant columns and number of rows, then aggregate by day giving `m_tc`.

As for the question, create an auxiliary variable `mdia` by formating the dates column as month-day only. Compute the means grouping by `mdia`. The result is a data.frame with 366 rows and 2 columns as expected.

```r
set.seed(2022)

# number of rows in the question
n <- 131496L
dia <- seq(as.Date("2007-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-31"), by = "1 day")
md <- data.frame(
  dia = sort(sample(dia, n, TRUE)),
  tc_h = round(runif(n, 0, 40), 1)
)

m_tc <- aggregate(tc_h ~ dia, md, mean)
mdia <- format(m_tc$dia, "%m-%d")
final <- aggregate(tc_h ~ mdia, m_tc, mean)

str(final)
#> 'data.frame':    366 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ mdia: chr  "01-01" "01-02" "01-03" "01-04" ...
#>  $ tc_h: num  20.2 20.4 20.2 19.6 20.7 ...

head(final, n = 10L)
#>     mdia     tc_h
#> 1  01-01 20.20741
#> 2  01-02 20.44143
#> 3  01-03 20.20979
#> 4  01-04 19.63611
#> 5  01-05 20.69064
#> 6  01-06 18.89658
#> 7  01-07 20.15992
#> 8  01-08 19.53639
#> 9  01-09 19.52999
#> 10 01-10 19.71914
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>